# Is there any difference between directly implementing an interface and implementing it through another?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

That is, If I have the interfaces:

```
public interface Foo { }

public interface Bar { }

public interface Baz : Foo, Bar { }
```

And I have a class `Qux`, would there be any code (except for reflection based on the exact interfaces, or stuff that wouldn't work because one version doesn't implement `Baz`) that would function differently depending on if `Qux` was declared like this:

```
public class Qux : Foo, Bar { }
```

versus this?

```
public class Qux : Baz { }
```

Comment: I think you managed to exclude pretty much every possible difference between the two in your "except for" part without meaning to do so. Can you edit that to more specifically explain which differences you're already aware of?

Comment: @hvd I'm aware that one `Qux` doesn't implement `Baz`, and I'm aware that `Type.GetInterfaces()` would be different.

Comment: "Function differently" how? The two options are obviously completely different in terms of how the interface members are implemented. In some ways, this leads to different "functioning" as the code is actually executed. On the other hand, the whole point of interfaces is so that an object can be treated as the interface instead of its own type and in that respect, it doesn't matter where the implementation comes from. On the third hand, `Baz` may well implement the interfaces different than `Qux` would, so again we're back to them being different. It's far from clear what you're asking.

Comment: Your Qux implementation is just fine as posted, but the two only match when Baz is empty.  Of course nobody ever does that.  The term "interface inheritance" is bad broken.  It should include the word "obligation" somewhere.  Which is all that Baz does, it gives the class that implements it the obligation to also implement the Foo and Bar members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a relevant difference other than the obvious one that `Baz` isn't implemented.

In the C# specification (I'm looking at C# 4.0 section 13.4, but it should still be true for newer versions), it says:

> A class or struct that directly implements an interface also directly implements all of the interface's base interfaces implicitly.  This is true even if the class or struct doesn't explicitly list all base interfaces in the base class list.

This means that the following definitions are equivalent:

```
public class Qux : Baz {}
public class Qux : Baz, Foo, Bar {}
```

It will even let you explicitly implement `Foo` interface methods even though it's not explicitly listed as a base interface:

```
public interface Foo { void FooMethod(); }
public interface Bar { void BarMethod(); }
public interface Baz : Foo, Bar { }
public class Qux : Baz
{
    void Foo.FooMethod() { } // legal
    public void BarMethod() { }
}
```

So all the differences should relate to the `Baz` interface only.

There *are* differences if `Baz` is a base *class* instead of an interface.  Section 13.4.5 and 13.4.6 state that the derived class doesn't change the interface mapping unless the interface is explicitly reimplemented.  For example:

```
public interface Foo { string FooMethod(); }
public class Baz : Foo { public string FooMethod() { return "Baz"; } }
public class Qux : Baz { public new string FooMethod() { return "Qux"; } }
```

The mapping for `Foo.FooMethod` for `Qux` would still be `Baz.FooMethod`:

```
Foo x = new Qux();
x.FooMethod(); // returns "Baz"
```

But if you instead did...

```
public class Qux : Baz, Foo { ... }
```

... it would reimplement the interface and `x.FooMethod()` would return "Qux".

It's worth noting that if you combine the two, such as...

```
public interface Baz : Foo, Bar {}
public class QuxBase : Baz {}
public class Qux : QuxBase, Baz {}
```

... then `Qux` will still act as if it were defined as `public class Qux : QuxBase, Baz, Foo, Bar`:

> When a class implement an interface, it implicitly also implements all of that interface's base interfaces.  Likewise, a reimplementation of an interface is also implicitly a reimplementation of all of the interface's base interfaces.

So even in this situation, the only difference between implementing `Baz` and implementing `Foo, Bar` is whether `Baz` itself is implemented.

In other words, if you never use the `Baz` interface itself, there's no difference I can find.